# C++ std::thread and std::async tests are in progress, but an error occurs

Tags: c++, stdthread, stdasync

I am trying to identify the difference between std::::thread and std:async through a simple experiment.(check std::async Thread Pool functionality)

However, an error occurs during execution.

[image]

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

thread test.

```
void for_print(int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        printf("%d Thread : %d\n", num, i);
}


int main(){
    std::vector<std::thread> v_thread(2000);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        v_thread.emplace_back(std::thread(for_print, i));

    //join()
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        v_thread[i].join();

    std::vector<std::thread>().swap(v_thread);
    return 0;
}
```

async test

```
void for_print(int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        printf("%d async : %d\n", num, i);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::future<void>> v_async(2000);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        v_async.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, for_print, i));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        v_async[i].wait();

    std::vector<std::future<void>>().swap(v_async);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error occurs? Quote it in full. How else can anyone confidently tell you what the problem is?

Comment: _an error occurs_ — Which error? Please, provide a complete error message and build configuration info (compiler, flags, etc.)

Comment: I have attached a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::thread> v_thread(2000);

for (size_t i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
   v_thread.emplace_back(std::thread(for_print, i));

for (size_t i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
   v_thread[i].join();
```

This is wrong. You first create a vector of 2000 "empty" thread objects, then add additional 2000 "living" threads, and finally join those first 2000 thread, which are not joinable.

The same holds in the case of `std::async`.

Just change

```
std::vector<std::thread> v_thread(2000);
```

to

```
std::vector<std::thread> v_thread;
```

and

```
std::vector<std::future<void>> v_async(2000);
```

to

```
std::vector<std::future<void>> v_async;
```

---

OT: These lines:

```
std::vector<std::thread>().swap(v_thread);
return 0;
```

at the end of `main` are completely superfluous.

---

**EDIT**

Also note that systems typically have some limit for the number of running threads. Creating 2000 threads might therefore be a problem also in this context.

Comment: Adding a `v_thread.reserve(2000);` could also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I have a question.
Does the thread release from memory after .join() step?

Comment: @HwanE Vector releases its memory (buffer) in its destructor, which is called automatically at the end of `main`.